# What’s the pitch of やっぱ (やっぱり)?

Tags: pitch-accent

In https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E5%A4%A7%E8%BE%9E%E6%9E%97/exact/%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B1, it’s listed as [0][3] but for the most part I think [1] やっぱ is more common overall.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [1] is more common.

The page you link is from 大辞林 which tends to be very old/traditional in the accents it lists. You should not trust it for anything slangy like this.

三省堂国語辞典 第八版 lists やっぱ as [1].